# how do i use 2 whatsapp accounts in my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have only one phone, an iphone, but have to access 2 whatsapp accounts. In android, we can use parallel space and have two whatsapp installations. But, iphone doesn't have any such option. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately without jailbreaking the phone or using untrusted sources there are no methods to use two different whatsapp account on the iphone

Answer (score 0):

any solution will work until the new update is pushed, after that the secondary account will cease to open

Answer (score -2):

install two whatsapp on iphone or ipad 2017 March

http://www.informationtech.co.in/how-to-use-two-whatsapp-accounts-on-iphone-without-jailbreak/

Comment: Please use caution loading any apps from non app store sources. It's hard to know if an app has been tampered with or will abuse your data or privacy.